# Full Cache Control using php

Tags: php, apache, caching

I have a website with dynamic pages.

I want to set the cache for images (all my gif, jpg and png) and css files to a specified time (1 month)

I want the browser to confirm if the files are still same on the server before serving cache copy.

How can i go about it via PHP?

Answer (score 2):

We do this at the web server level, apache in our case (this question is also tagged with `apache`) using [mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html).

You could do this with the following directives in your `httpd.conf`, or similar:

```
ExpiresByType image/gif  "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png  "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css   "access plus 1 month"
```